# Implement click-action in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently trying to find my way into MVC and at the moment I'm facing the following problem:

When it comes to MVC, I have learnt that it is important to strictly divide Model, View and Controller. For example there should be no Business Logic in a View. But now I have the situation, that I would like to update one cell of my DataTable when a button is clicked. My cell looks like this

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ElementAt(0).Ready)
```

and represents a boolean value (`Ready`). By clicking the button I would like to negate this boolean.

So what is the best way to reach this? What is the necessary functionality and where should I implement it (Model, View, Controller), so that I can also update my database?

I really appreciate any help!

PS: In particular, if I had to use JS, how do I get control of `@Html.DisplayFor`.

Comment: Why not use `CheckboxFor`? That seems more suited to a `boolean`.

Comment: "I have learnt that it is important to strictly divide Model, View and Controller" besides the physical separation (you have 3 different files), where exactly you put business logic isn't strictly predetermined. It's also extremely common to have server-side MVC and client-side MVC/MVVM given that you shouldn't make HTTP requests for changing *everything* in the UI

Comment: @RyanWilson And how do I get this to change?